# Rails: Resourceful routes using either UUID or Slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I want to allow my resourceful routes to get the record via either the UUID parameter or the Slug.

Basically I want `/users/aafdbc47-b427-4be9-bf4b-4b6c4e9b8303` or `/users/sireltonjohn` to work. These are two separate fields in my schema, UUID and Slug respectively. Primarily so I have a non-changing direct link to the user (since the user can change their Slug).

I'm a relative newb to Rails so I'm trying to figure out how, in my routes.rb, to allow that route to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `/users/aafdbc47-b427-4be9-bf4b-4b6c4e9b8303` and `/users/sireltonjohn` are routed to `users/:id` which is the `show` action from `UsersController` (if we are following the rails convetions)

Here's a simple way to do it (wrote this from mind)

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationRecord
  before_action :find_user, only: :show

  def show
    p @user
  end

  private
  
  def find_user
    @user = User.where('uuid = :key OR slug = :key', key: params[:id]).first
  end 
end

# routes.rb
resources :users
```

You could check [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), see if it suits you.